# Google OAuth Verification not required but there is still 100-user cap

Tags: google-oauth

After clicking the "PUBLISH APP" button, the Verification Status was set to:

> Verification not required:
> Your consent screen is being shown, but your
> app has not been reviewed so your users may not see all of your
> information, and you will not be able to request certain OAuth scopes.

However, the problem is that the OAuth user cap is still set to 100 users.

[OAuth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gU77.png)